# How can I set the img in the slider?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web, slider

```
const slides = [
  {
    eachSlide: "url(https://www.consilium.europa.eu/media/54319/erasmus.png)",
  },
  {
    eachSlide: "url(https://unsplash.it/1900/1024/?image=291)",
  },
  {
    eachSlide: "url(https://unsplash.it/1900/1024/?image=786)",
  },
  {
    eachSlide: "url(https://unsplash.it/1900/1024/?image=768)",
  },
  {
    eachSlide: "url(https://unsplash.it/1900/1024/?image=726)",
  },
  {
    eachSlide: "url(https://unsplash.it/1900/1024/?image=821)",
  },
];
```

```
.slider {
  width: 85vw;
  height: 65vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.slider .each-slide {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  image-rendering: auto;
  float: left;
  line-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 40vh;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

The slider feature was broken when it was necessary to change the width and height.A different image I added does not fit in this range.It looks like it's half-fitted.How can I give width-height to a different image I added?

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which demonstrates the problem. You can even create a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/), to make your code runnable from within the question you posted.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create sliders easily  you can use the slick.js library
[slickJs](https://react-slick.neostack.com/)

Comment: thanks, i already created it. When I add different images, it doesn't fit inside.